# TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'confirm_success_url'

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, devise

Having a problem with an angular module in all browsers **EXCEPT** for Firefox called "ng-token-auth". On the rails server I'm using the gem "devise-token-auth" which works seamlessly with the angular module to create an API token authentication framework.

The problem I'm having is to do with the `$auth.SubmitRegistration()` method. Following the example posted on github (https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/ng-token-auth#authsubmitregistration) in my users_registration.coffee ngController I am sending the form data (converted to JSON) through a variable into the SubmitRegistration() function which is then posted to rails (handled by the devise-token-auth) gem.

**However, immediately** on form submission before any data has been posted a javascript error is thrown stating: `TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'confirm_success_url' of`

user_registrations.coffee (controller):

```
angular.module('Authentication').controller('UserRegistrationsController',['$scope', '$rootScope','$auth','$state',
($scope, $rootScope, $auth, $state) ->
$scope.handleRegBtnClick = ->

  r = $rootScope.availability
  f = $scope.registrationForm

  parameter = JSON.stringify(
    zone_id: r.zone.id
    first_name: f.first_name
    last_name: f.last_name
    email: f.email
    password: f.password)

  $auth.submitRegistration(parameter).then ->
    $auth.submitLogin
      email: $scope.registrationForm.email
      password: $scope.registrationForm.password
 ])
```

form.html:

```
<form ng-submit="handleRegBtnClick()" role="form" ng-init="registrationForm =  {}">
<div class="form-group">
<label for="first_name">First Name</label>
<input type="first_name"
       name="first_name"
       id="first_name"
       ng-model="registrationForm.first_name"
       required="required"
       class="form-control">
</div>
........
 <div class="form-group">
<label for="email">Email</label>
<input type="email"
       name="email"
       id="email"
       ng-model="registrationForm.email"
       required="required"
       class="form-control">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label for="password">Password</label>
<input type="password"
       name="password"
       id="password"
       ng-model="registrationForm.password"
       required="required"
       class="form-control">
</div>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Register</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up solving this issue. The problem was coming from using `JSON.stringify` whereas I needed to use `angular.extend`

```
parameter = angular.extend(
zone_id: r.zone_id
.....
```

I didn't realize but `confirm_success_url` is a parameter that gets added automatically along with the data so before it was not being included with the other parameters.

Anyhow, it now works in all browsers.